# Use your local types for an npm package without publishing it to @types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use this npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-notification) so I created a index.d.ts file in node_modules/@types/react-web-notification folder:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface propTypes {
    ignore?: bool,
    disableActiveWindow?: bool,
    askAgain?: bool,
    notSupported?: func,
    onPermissionGranted?: func,
    onPermissionDenied?: func,
    onShow?: func,
    onClick?: func,
    onClose?: func,
    onError?: func,
    timeout?: number,
    title?: string.isRequired,
    options?: object,
    swRegistration?: object,
};

declare class Notification extends React.Component<propTypes, any> {}

export default Notification
```

and it worked ok. But obviously I don't want to keep it there because it is ignored. I don't want to publish it to @types github repo because it takes ages to clone that repo.

So I tried to use it locally in my react app src folder:
NotificationInterface.tsx:

```
    import * as React from 'react';

interface propTypes {
    ignore?: boolean,
    disableActiveWindow?: boolean,
    askAgain?: boolean,
    notSupported?: Function,
    onPermissionGranted?: Function,
    onPermissionDenied?: Function,
    onShow?: Function,
    onClick?: Function,
    onClose?: Function,
    onError?: Function,
    timeout?: number,
    title?: string,
    options?: object,
    swRegistration?: object,
}

declare class Notification extends React.Component<propTypes, any> {}

export default Notification
```

and then in my app:

```
import Notification from "../NotificationInterface";
...

    return (
             <main>
                    <Notification
                        ignore={this.state.ignore && this.state.title !== ''}
                        onPermissionGranted={this.handlePermissionGranted}
                        onPermissionDenied={this.handlePermissionDenied}
                        onShow={this.handleNotificationOnShow}
                        onClick={this.handleNotificationOnClick}
                        onClose={this.handleNotificationOnClose}
                        onError={this.handleNotificationOnError}
                        timeout={60000}
                        title={this.state.title}
                        options={this.state.options}
                    />
```

But now I got an error:
Failed to construct 'Notification': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Why would it work when it is in @types folder and not now?

Comment: Typescript looks for a types in `node_modules/@types` by default. More info here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: @AlekseyL. so there is no way to use the types from a file in my src folder?

Comment: There's, but you'll need to define it in slightly different way. I'll add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how you can provide a typings to untyped module. Add a file with below content and include it in project files:

```
declare module 'react-web-notification' {
    import * as React from 'react';

    interface Props {
        ignore?: boolean,
        disableActiveWindow?: boolean,
        askAgain?: boolean,
        notSupported?: Function,
        onPermissionGranted?: Function,
        onPermissionDenied?: Function,
        onShow?: Function,
        onClick?: Function,
        onClose?: Function,
        onError?: Function,
        timeout?: number,
        title: string,
        options?: object,
        swRegistration?: object,
    }
    class Notification extends React.Component<Props> {}

    export = Notification;
}
```

Pay attention to module declaration.

Side note - you can contribute the declarations to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped and once published you'll be able to consume them in "regular" way